# Why isn't "export default" recommended in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

According to the [Typescript documentation (section "Guidance for structuring modules")](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html):

> *If you’re only exporting a single class or function, use export
>   default*
>
> Just as “exporting near the top-level” reduces friction on your
>   module’s consumers, so does introducing a default export. If a
>   module’s primary purpose is to house one specific export, then you
>   should consider exporting it as a default export. This makes both
>   importing and actually using the import a little easier.

Example:

```
export default class SomeType {
  constructor() { ... }
}
```

In the [Angular documentation for components](https://angular.io/guide/architecture#components) (for example) one sees this:

```
export class HeroListComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[];
  selectedHero: Hero;

  constructor(private service: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.heroes = this.service.getHeroes();
  }

  selectHero(hero: Hero) { this.selectedHero = hero; }
}
```

Generally, a component's or module's primary purpose is to house one specific export. So, is there a reason why Angular does not use or recommend using `export default`?

Comment: Probably for the same reason people use braces around a single statement in if/else branches - for consistency, and for minimizing changes to the code when you need to add second statement or export. And consistency actually makes importing easier - I don't need to check if  a module has a default export or not every time I need to import something.

Comment: Don't confuse TypeScript language issues with this question. I've read somewhere that default export on components breaks the ahead of time compiler in Angular. Why this happens I don't know, but sometimes you should just follow the documentation. We could use an answer from someone of authority on the Angular team to clarify this issue, and that's why I asked for it not to be closed. It's a perfectly good question and I don't like people writing it off as a tabs or spaces issue.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The actual reason is that this doesn't work with the AOT compiler, however it will work with the JIT compiler. So if you are using AOT (or want to use it moving forward), don't do export default.
See also [here](https://github.com/UltimateAngular/aot-loader/wiki/Limitations-with-AoT):

> Default Exports
>
> Default exports aren't allowed with AoT - they must all be named.
>
> ❌ DONT:
>
> ```
> import { Component } from '@angular/core';
>
> @Component({
>   template: `
>     <div class="example">
>       Example component!
>     </div>
>   `
> })
> export default class ExampleComponent {
>
> }
> ```
>
> ✅ DO:
>
> ```
> import { Component } from '@angular/core';
>
> @Component({
>   template: `
>     <div class="example">
>       Example component!
>     </div>
>   `
> })
> export class ExampleComponent {
>
> }
> ```

Comment: The other **DONT'S** are interesting too. In case anyone is wondering, the last line under "Private properties" should be "Use the @internal comment above them or make them **public**."

Comment: You saved my life xD

Answer (score 1):

I don't said `export default` is not recommended in Angular. I since it's tottaly up to you and relative to your coding preferences. Some of developers avoid Export Default because of maintainability and refactoring concerns.

But you need to know `export default` is now fully supported by Angular. Take this part of the documentation about *[Lazy loading and default exports](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#lazy-loading-and-default-exports)* for loadChildren() as an exemple.

Regarding to AOT compiler bug, The problem seems to be soved since March 2020 (**[#11402](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11402#issuecomment-599224371)**)

See **[this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77524025/11630806)** for more details about it.