# Why angular use `import { SomeComponent } from 'some.component.ts'` instead of `import SomeComponent from 'some.component.ts'`

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I write React/Vue. As usual, I like to export/import a default component.

```
// export
export default class SomeComponent from Component {
    // blahblah
}

// import
import SomeComponent from './some.js'
```

But when I use angular2+, I found a strange thing.
It uses destructive import/export form.

```
// export
@Component({/* ... */})
export class SomeComponent {
    // blahblah
}

// import
import {SomeComponent} from './some.component.ts'
```

Why? I think it a little troublesome. It's defined by Typescript rules or contributor?

Comment: you've forgotten to press set as `default` button :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't "export default" recommended in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962317/why-isnt-export-default-recommended-in-angular)

Answer (score 1):

If you add `default` before `class` then you gonna be able to import in in the same way as in React/Vue.

Answer (score 1):

A typescript or javascript file can export multiple class( or functions, constants). Due to this behaviour you export your class( or functions, constants) in this fashion:

```
export class MyClass{}
```

and import in this fashion:

```
// import
import {MyClass} from './myClass.ts'
```

If you are sure that you will export only single class( or functions, constants) then just use following syntax:

```
//export
export default class MyClass{}
//import
import MyClass from "./myclass.ts"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard behavior.

It allows you to export several things out of your file.

For instance

```
export class MyClass {}
export const MyClassMockedForTesting = {};
```

But if you want to change that, you can use the `default` keyword like so

```
export default class MyClass {}
```

It will export your class and you won't need brackets anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Angular Doesn't use default imports on its packages because default imports are not good. Other people have covered why in seperate posts so i'll link to one here.
https://blog.neufund.org/why-we-have-banned-default-exports-and-you-should-do-the-same-d51fdc2cf2ad

Answer (score 0):

If you use 'import some from somecomponent' unless there is only one export moudel in the somecomponent,if there are more than one export moudle,you must use {} to specified import which moudle