# Can't resolve all parameters for component when service is injected

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular-services

I have a problem when i am injecting service into my component. The service is provided globaly.
I get this error in my code editor.

> Can't resolve all parameters for SomeComponent in some.component.ts: (?). ng(0)

The strange thing is that my app works and compiler doesn't throw any errors.

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export default class AppService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  someMethod() {}
}
```

**Component**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import AppService from "./app.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-some-component"
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private _appService: AppService) {}
}
```

I was looking through answers here and couldn't get to any that provides answer.
Some answers gave solution to change order of constructor injections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a number of tries, i figured that i made a mistake of `export  default class AppService`.

I found out that it is not recommended to use default exports in Angular because AOT wont work. Here is the article that covers that problem: [Why isn't "export default" recommended in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962317/why-isnt-export-default-recommended-in-angular/45963067)

So solution is to always export normally a class:

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AppService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  someMethod() {}
}
```

**Component**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { AppService } from "./app.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-some-component"
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private _appService: AppService) {}
}
```

Hope this helps someone not lose hours like me.