# how to set `export default class` when generating components instead of `export class`

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular-components

I don't know if setting `export default` for my components is a bad practice, I'm new to Angular and I want to do it because I want to import the component without the curly braces

I want the `ng g c home` generate this:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export default class HomeComponent { // Note the default modifier.

}
```

So I can import it in any component without the curly braces

```js
import HomeComponent from "./home/home.component";
```

Comment: Using named exports forces you to use the right name for the import, which some people prefer. Not saying that it's a bad practice, but you'll probably get opionated answers.

Comment: Read here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962317/why-isnt-export-default-recommended-in-angular

Comment: @SharpDev, Really interesting post. If i understand correctly, as long as i use `ng build` and not `ng build --aot` it's working fine. I know AOT compiler is more suitable for production but it's a really interesting point. Any reference in Angular doc to this?

Comment: @SharpDev Interesting, so this seems like a limitation of the aot compiler. Does this still exist or has it been fixed since 2017?

Answer (score 4):

## Angular and the use of `export default`

Regarding to the all snippet in Angular documentation, it seems that the use of `default` is only recommended for the routes files of an Angular application. The Angular ecosystem and development tools are primarily designed to work with the standard export syntax. It seem's to be changing since the last 2 years.

According to [this part](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#lazy-loading-and-default-exports)  of the Angular documentation and also [this #issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/46323) in the Angular Github repository, now Angular 15+ support default exports. For exemple, in loadChildren or loadComponent callbacks, you can do :

```
/* app.routes.ts */
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadComponent: () => import('./home/home.component'),
  }
];

/* home.component.ts */
@Component({ /* ... */ })
export default class HomeComponent {}
```

## AOT and JIT compiler

In **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45963067/11630806)** related post, in 2017, the 'export default' seem to have issues with AOT compiler (`ng build --aot`). This was [fixed](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11402#issuecomment-599224371) in March 2020. I don't have any issue using `export default` in my testing so far.

## Using a custom template in Angular CLI

If you want to use `export default` by default in a component template, i suggest the use of **[Angular schematics](https://angular.io/guide/schematics)**. You just need to create schematic template for a custom component with `export default` and then call your custom component from your angular CLI. Your schematic template can look like :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '<%= selector %>',
  templateUrl: './<%= dasherize(name) %>.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./<%= dasherize(name) %>.component.css']
})
export default class <%= classify(name) %><%= classify(type) %> {

  constructor() { }

}
```

Comment: How do I create a custom schematic?

Comment: @otaxhu, It's a large question for another post i think ;). Quickly, keep in mind schematics isn't a one line solution but a powerfull tool to customize the code generate by your CLI. you need to dedicate a npm project to it and link it to your project. To start with schematics, and do exactly what you want to achieve, you can see this very detailed tutorial : https://medium.com/atlas/angular-schematics-simple-schematic-76be2aa72850

Answer (score 1):

Like @bergi said, I will bring you "opionated answer" regarding to Angular Good practice.

I will **avoid Export Default** because of maintainability concerns and easy refactoring. But this is purely personal. I just prefer read `import { Foo } from "./foo";`. In fact, it's easy to confuse default exports and named ones while importing from the same package.

That being said from now on you can use export default in Angular without having issue with AOT compiller. In the doc you can find a case for the use of export default [`here`](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#lazy-loading-and-default-exports)

If you want to use it in the Angular CLI tool, i can suggest you to look over `Angular Schematics`

Comment: Thank you so much for `Angular Schematics`, exactly was i looking for ! But i not seeing why your link is related to AOT compiler

Answer (score -1):

As of now there is no way to generate components with default exports using angular cli, you have to manually update component after generation to make it default export.

If you are coming from React, you are likely to be comfortable with default exports but in angular it is recomended to use named exports as unlike react, angular follows strict structure and using default exports may incurr errors in things like aot compilation etc.